# Draw to GdkWindow root window with Gtk3 and Cairo

Tags: gtk3, cairo

I want to be able to draw directly to the root window with Gtk3 using Cairo. I have and old Gtk2 code drawing on a fullscreened window like this:

```
GdkWindow* drawable; 
GdkGC* gc;

drawable = gdk_screen_get_root_window (gdk_screen_get_default());

gc = gdk_gc_new (drawable);
gdk_gc_set_subwindow (gc, GDK_INCLUDE_INFERIORS);

...

do_draw(drawable, gc);
```

With Gtk3 I tried this,

```
GdkWindow* drawable; 

drawable = gdk_screen_get_root_window (gdk_screen_get_default());

cairo_surface_t *source_surface = gdk_window_create_similar_surface (drawable, CAIRO_CONTENT_COLOR_ALPHA, gdk_window_get_width(drawable), gdk_window_get_height(drawable) );
cairo_t *cairo = cairo_create(source_surface);
cairo_set_source_surface(cairo, source_surface, 0, 0);

....
do_draw(cairo);
```

The code seems to runs fine, but nothing is ever drawn to the screen.  Is there a way to do something similar with Gtk3 and Cairo?

Answer (score 0):

`gdk_window_create_similar_surface` creates a new surface that is "similar" to an already given one. But it is still a new surface.

You are looking for `gdk_cairo_create()` instead, I think (which is deprecated).

---

Unrelated to your question, but what is the following code supposed to do? Why are you preparing to copy a surface to itself? I think that is not really an allowed operation in cairo.

```
cairo_t *cairo = cairo_create(source_surface);
cairo_set_source_surface(cairo, source_surface, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for an alternative option for `gdk_cairo_create` which is now deprecated, so I decided to use `gdk_window_create_similar_surface` after reading this post [drawing-in-gtk](https://blog.gtk.org/2016/06/15/drawing-in-gtk/)